# Android - Fragment Views get NULL outside onCreateView

Tags: java, android, android-activity, null, fragment

i have a Fragment and the View is stored into a Class variable in onCreateView:

```
    private FrameLayout mView;
    private TextView countdown;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle bdl) {
            mView = (FrameLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.vakit_fragment, container, false);
            countdown = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.countdown);
    ...
            return mView;

    }
```

both are non-Null here and wont be modified anywhere in my code.

later this is called from the Main Activity:

```
         MainFragment frag = (MainFragment) mAdapter.getItem(mPager.getCurrentItem());
         if(frag!=null) {
         frag.onSecond();
         }
```

and in the Fragment:

```
protected void onSecond(){
    String left=times.getLeft();


    if(countdown!=null)     
        countdown.setText(left);

}
```

in onSecond both mView and countdown are ever NULL, why? I cant explain it.

metin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you create another instance of your Fragments in the adapter.getItem() Method.

Comment: should it get the current instance?

Comment: It depends what you need,your ViewPager is responsible for doing this. Normally the ViewPager caches some of its Fragments like the left and right one. But you can do how ever you what.

Comment: yes thank you, i call getItem() and that give me a new instance.

Answer (score 3):

`onCreateView` is called only when the fragment draws the UI. In this case, `onSecond` is called before `onCreateView`, so `mView` hasn't been inflated yet, which is why it's null. You can get around this by putting the `onSecond` logic into `onCreateView`.